# What's the difference between reserved and committed memory?

Tags: windows, memory-management

I understand that memory has to be reserved before being committed.  And when it's reserved, no other process can use it. However reserved memory does not count against available RAM. But shouldn't it? Because if no one else can use it, then what good is it being "available"?

Or is there some bigger difference?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for where you found that definition of "reserved"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Check out Mark Russinovich's presentation at PDC 10.  It was called 'PDC10: Mysteries of Windows Memory Management Revealed: Part One.' He talks extensively about this. http://player.microsoftpdc.com

Comment: Mark Russinovich's presentation found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjTl53I_qzY

Comment: @fractor many thanks.

Answer (score 55):

In the context of Win32, "reserved" means that the address space is allocated *within the process that requested it*. This may be used, for example, to reserve space for a large buffer that's not all needed right away, but when it's needed it would need to be contiguous.

Reserving memory does not interact with other processes at all, since each process has its own private address space. So the statement that "when it's reserved, no other process can use it" is meaningless, since processes can't normally allocate memory in the address space of another process anyway.

When the reserved pages are requested to be committed (backing store allocated for them), that operation can potentially fail due to lack of physical memory (or pagefile).

Comment: "backing store allocated for them": Do you mean when data that's only stored in cache is called reserved, and when it's written to RAM or pagefile it's called committed?

Comment: @pydave: No, "cache" and "reserved" are unrelated concepts. Reserving memory is sort of like a property developer claiming land that will later contain houses. There's nothing there yet, but nobody else can build houses there either. Committing is actually building the houses and setting up the infrastructure like electricity and sewer. On the other hand, cache is an optimisation to make CPUs run faster, all data is still stored somewhere in RAM.

Comment: So does writing data to a memory page cause that page to be committed? (Then the difference between reserved and committed is that reserved has been allocated, but committed has been used.)

Comment: @pydave: In Windows, committing memory is a separate step that must happen before trying to write to the memory (writing to uncommitted pages will generally cause a page fault). See the [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for more info.

Comment: @idbrii No. Reserving and committing have nothing to do with allocation of physical memory, ie RAM - only virtual. The first memory access to a committed page is what causes a page of RAM to be allocated for it and associated with it. This is why committed can be so much larger than the physical usage - many apps commit a lot more than they end up actually using.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: No, reserved and committed memory has nothing to do with the placement new operation in C++.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: A good place to start is the [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: No, "regular mallocing" is far past the stage of "reserved" memory from a Win32 perspective, and is already committed. Committed memory is a concept not directly related to the swap file. The way to *reserve* memory in Win32 is to use `VirtualAlloc`. The `malloc` runtime library function gives you committed memory, and you know this because you can immediately read from and write to it. (If it were only reserved memory and not committed, you would get a page fault.)

Answer (score 16):

I like to view `Reserved` as booking the **address** space so that no one else can allocate it (but I can't use memory at that address because it is not yet available). And `Committed` as *mapping* that address space to the **physical memory** so that it can be used.

Why would I want to *reserve*? Why not just get committed memory? There are several reasons I have in mind:

1. Some application needs a specific address range, say from 0x400000 to 0x600000, but does not need the memory for storing anything. It is used to trap memory access. E.g., if some code accesses such area, it will be caught. (Useful for some reason.)
2. Some thread needs to store progressively expanding data. And the data needs to be in one contiguous chunk of memory. It is preferred not to commit large physical memory at one go because it is not needed and would be such a waste. The memory can be utilized by some other threads first. The physical memory is committed only on demand.

Comment: For 2, unless that data is touched, no space is actually allocated (which also includes page table structures such as PTEs) in the working set, however the paging file(s) will grow to guarantee that the memory can be used when required. Which would indeed be quite an inefficient use of disk space.

Answer (score 11):

Process Virtual Memory (Address Space ) and Actual RAM are both different. you can have 512MB physical RAM but still your process can address 4GB virtual address space(2GB Userspace)
Every address in a process can be thought of as either free, reserved, or committed at any given time.

A process begins with all addresses free, meaning they are free to be committed
to memory or reserved for future use.Before any free address may be used, it must first be allocated as reserved **OR** committed. But doesn't need to be reserved in order for it to be committed.

reserving memory means reserving virtaul address space for future purposes. it doesn't associated with Physical RAM (mapped to RAM Addresses).where as committed memory means it will be associated with actual RAM so that you can store data in it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx

Comment: A quibble: Virtual memory doesn't need to be reserved _as a separate step_ before it's committed. VirtualAlloc can reserve and commit in one call. But the "reserve" does have to be done. Also, committing does not actually "allocate" RAM; only a subsequent page fault does that. I (tried to?) edit "it will be associated" to "it can be associated" accordingly. I would also add the following sentence to the end: "Actual RAM isn't allocated until you access the committed region, and is done on a page-by-page basis." And one other thing: Another way to use free pages is for mapped memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer is that:

- you reserve memory in **virtual** address space, so that no other part of code **within the same process** gets it
- you commit memory to **physical** RAM/swap so that no **other process** gets it

So for example if a process has mem limit of 1 GB and does malloc reserve of 1 GB at start it cannot malloc any more even though process memory usage at OS level (commited memory) is nearly 0.