# Committed vs Reserved Memory

Tags: memory, memory-management

According to "*Windows Internals, Part 1*" (7th Edition, Kindle version):

> Pages in a process virtual address space are either free, reserved, committed, or shareable.

Focusing only on the `reserved` and `committed` pages, the first type is described in the same book:

> Reserving memory means setting aside a range of contiguous virtual addresses for possible future use (such as an array) while consuming negligible system resources, and then committing portions of the reserved space as needed as the application runs. Or, if the size requirements are known in advance, a process can reserve and commit in the same function call.

Both reserving or committing will initially get you entries in the VADs (virtual address descriptors), but neither operation will touch the PTE (page table entries) structures. It used to cost PTEs for reserving before Windows 8.1, [but not anymore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160701-00/?p=93785).

As described above, `reserved` means blocking a range of virtual addresses, NOT blocking physical memory or paging file space at the OS level. The OS doesn't include this in the commit limit, therefore when the time comes to allocate this memory, you might get a surprise. It's important to note that reserving happens from the perspective of the process address space. It's not that there's any physical resource reserved - there's no stamping of "no vacancy" against RAM space or page file(s).

The analogy with plots of land might be missing something: take `reserved` as the area of land surrounded by wooden poles, thus letting others now that the land is taken. But how about `committed` ? It can't be land on which structures (eg houses) have already been build, since those would require PTEs and there's none there yet, since we haven't accessed anything. It's only when touching `committed` data that the PTEs will get built, which will make the pages available to the process.

The main problem is that `committed` memory - at least in its initial state - is functionally very much alike `reserved` memory. It's just an area blocked within VADs. Try to touch one of the addresses, and you'll get an access violation exception for a `reserved` address:

> Attempting to access free or reserved memory results in an access violation exception because the page isn’t mapped to any storage that can resolve the reference

...and an initial page fault for a `committed` one (immediately followed by the required PTE entries being created).

Back to the land analogy, once houses are build, that patch of land is still `committed`. Yet this is a bit peculiar, since it was still `committed` when the original grass was there, before the very first shovel was excavated to start construction. It resembled the same state as that of a reserved patch. Maybe it would be better to think of it like terrain eligible for construction. Eg you have a permit to build (albeit you might never build as much as a wall on that patch of land).

What would be the reasons for using one type of memory versus the other ? There's at least one: the OS guarantees that there will be room to allocate `committed` memory, should that ever occur in the future, but doesn't guarantee anything for `reserved` memory aside from blocking that process' address space range. The only downside for `committed` memory is that one or more paging files might need to be extended in size as to be able to make the commit limit take into account the recently allocated block, so should the requester demand the use of part of all the data in the future, the OS can provide access to it.

I can't really think how the land analogy can capture this detail of "guarantee". After all, the `reserved` patch also physically existed, covered by the same grass as a `committed` one in its  pristine state.

The stack is another scenario where `reserved` and `committed` memory are used together:

> When a thread is created, the memory manager automatically reserves a predetermined amount of virtual memory, which by default is 1 MB.[...] Although 1 MB is reserved, only the first page of the stack will be committed [...]
>    along with a guard page. When a thread’s stack grows large enough to touch the guard page, an exception occurs, causing an attempt to allocate another guard. Through this mechanism, a user stack doesn’t immediately consume all 1 MB of committed memory but instead grows with demand."

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911596/5853218) that deals with why one would want to use `reserved` memory as opposed to `committed` . It involves storing continuously expanding data - which is actually the stack model described above - and having specific absolute address ranges available when needed (although I'm not sure why one would want to do that within a process).

Ok, what am I actually asking ?

1. What would be a good analogy for the `reserved`/`committed` concept ?
2. Any other reason aside those depicted above that would mandate the
   use of `reserved` memory ? Are there any interesting use cases when
   resorting to `reserved` memory is a smart move ?

Comment: For the analogy, Alex Ionescu - one of the authors of "Windows Internals" - provides a very good example: a restaurant. One can reserve a table ahead of time (eg have a block of virtual addresses reserved within your own process address space) and be confident that when you show up at the agreed time, your table will still be reserved. That doesn't mean however the dishes you'd like to order will be available, since others might have requested too many of them already for the day (eg the operating system honoured requests for other processes that actually committed memory). However...

Comment: ...should you pre-order the dishes you'd like to have ahead of time (and most likely having to pay in advance) will guarantee you the food you'd like at that specific time. In this case, the restaurant would have "committed" the food resources for preparing your dishes, as opposed to risk having them routed to someone else should there be such a demand.

Answer (score 3):

Your question hits upon the difference between logical memory translation and virtual memory translation. While CPU documentation likes to conflate these two concepts, they are different in practice.

If you look at logical memory translation, there are are only two states for a page. Using your terminology, they are FREE and COMMITTED. A free page is one that has no mapping to a physical page frame and a COMMITTED page has such a mapping.

In a virtual memory system, the operating system has to maintain a copy of the address space in secondary storage. How this is done depends upon the operating system. Typically, a process will have its mapping to several different files for secondary storage. The operating system divides the address space into what is usually called a SECTION.

For example, the code and read only data could be stored virtually as one or more  SECTIONS in the executable file. Code and static data in shared libraries could each be in a different section that are paged to the shared libraries. You might have a map to a shared filed to the process that uses memory that can be accessed by multiple processes that forms another section. Most of the read/write data is likely to be in a page file in one or more sections. How the operating system tracks where it virtually stores each section of data is system dependent.

For windows, that gives the definition of one of your terms: Sharable. A sharable section is one where a range of addresses can be mapped to different processes, at different (or possibly the same) logical addresses.

Your last term is then RESERVED. If you look at the Windows' [`VirtualAlloc`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) function documentation, you can see that (among your options) you can RESERVE or COMMIT. If you reserve you are creating a section of VIRTUAL MEMORY that has no mapping to physical memory.

This RESERVE/COMMIT model is Windows-specific (although other operating systems may do the same). The likely reason was to save disk space. When Windows NT was developed, 600MB drives the size of washing machine were still in use.

In these days of 64-bit address spaces, this system works well for (as you say) expanding data. In theory, an exception handler for a stack overrun can simply expand the stack. Reserving 4GB of memory takes no more resources than reserving a single page (which would not be practicable in a 32-bit system—see above). If you have 20 threads, this makes reserving stack space efficient.

> What would be a good analogy for the reserved/committed concept ?

One could say RESERVE is like buying options to buy and COMMIT is exercising the option.

> Any other reason aside those depicted above that would mandate the use of reserved memory ? Are there any interesting use cases when resorting to reserved memory is a smart move ?

IMHO, the most likely places to RESERVE without COMMITTING are for creating stacks and heaps with the former being the most important.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been going over it for a few times now. You mention that "In a virtual memory system, the operating system has to maintain a copy of the address space in secondary storage". However, Windows can successfully run with no paging file at all. As per Windows Internals: "In fact, even if you run with no page file at all, Windows will still be using virtual memory.". Later in the same book, but related to sections: "Because Windows can run with no paging file, page-file-backed sections might in fact be “backed” only by physical memory".

Comment: Or do yourself use the term "virtual memory" only when dealing with paging file(s) ? Because I understand what you're saying in regards to conflating the 2 notions. Trouble is my initial learning is based on the "Windows Internals" book, who appears to be using the system whereby virtual memory strictly refers to the liniar address space; whether that's backed up by paging file(s), it makes no difference.

Comment: If there is no paging, the it is logical memory translation—not virtual memory. Conflating the two concepts causes confusion. Virtual memory is going to go away in the future as system memory increases.

Comment: Thank you again. I've eventually got to read the first part of the AMD Architecture doc. The first 14 pages here made me learn new things: https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24593.pdf. Logical and virtual memory concepts are conflated, just like you said, but once this is clear, valuable info is to be gained.