# Commiting memory when initalizing VirtualSpace

Tags: java, c++, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I'm looking at `CodeHeap` initialization and was confused by the concept of "commited memory area" and `ReservedSpace`. Here is how the reservation [looks like](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#l303):

```
ReservedCodeSpace rs = reserve_heap_memory(cache_size);
ReservedSpace non_method_space    = rs.first_part(non_nmethod_size);
ReservedSpace rest                = rs.last_part(non_nmethod_size);
ReservedSpace profiled_space      = rest.first_part(profiled_size);
ReservedSpace non_profiled_space  = rest.last_part(profiled_size);
```

Reserving memory for code cache falls back to the [`base = os::reserve_memory(size, NULL, alignment, _fd_for_heap);`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.cpp#l199) which in turns calls `mmap` to do the virtual memory mapping we pass `ReservedCodeSpace rs` containing a pointer the space that was `mmap`ed before.

The thing that I do not understand is when invoking the [`!heap->reserve(rs, size_initial, CodeCacheSegmentSize)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#l419) we do so on the already reserved memory that `rs` holds a pointer to.

I ran `java -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m --version` with gdb and noticed that the code cache initialization `heap->reserve(rs, size_initial, CodeCacheSegmentSize)` calls [`_memory.initialize(rs, c_size)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/heap.cpp#l120) which in turns calls [`commit_expanded(middle_high(), middle_needs, _middle_alignment, pre_touch, _executable)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.cpp#l913) with `middle_needs = 2555904`.

What is this `middle_needs` and why do we need expansion? I thought all the virtual memory mapping required for code space is done in `ReservedCodeSpace` constructor

Comment: I'm confused about what you actually ask. Seems like you interchange "reserved" and "committed" terms, but they are [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440434/whats-the-difference-between-reserved-and-committed-memory). Also, I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to explain the source code which is already very well commented.

Comment: Just follow the comments in the code to see what is [middle region](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.hpp#l155), why [expand() is called](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.cpp#l717) and [how it works](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/memory/virtualspace.cpp#l832).

Comment: @apangin Yes, now the idea of it is more or less clear. Did not read comment comments carefully enough.