# Operator new behaves differently in Debug mode than in Release mode in MSVC

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, memory-management, page-fault

While testing some things regarding page faults I discovered a curious difference between how `new` operates in Debug mode and Release mode in MSVC. Consider the following code<sup>1</sup>:

```cpp
#include <array>

constexpr size_t PAGE_SIZE = 4096;

int main()
{
    const size_t count = 1000000;
    char* const mem = new char[PAGE_SIZE * count];

    // page align the pointer, c-style casts used for brevity
    auto* pages = (std::array<char, PAGE_SIZE>*)((size_t)mem - (size_t)mem % PAGE_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        pages[i][0] = 'a';
}
```

The code allocates a million normal memory [pages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210510-00/?p=105200) on most architectures. It then physically writes to this allocated memory, so the memory really has to be "given"<sup>2</sup> to the program - not merely "reserved" for it in some way. The curious thing is, when this actually happens. To investigate this, I stepped through the code using the Visual Studio debugger and looked at the memory usage graph in Task Manager. The results are below:

[image: Measurement results]

The red time point is the program being launched, the green time point/interval is the call to `new char[]`, the blue time point/interval is the `for` loop.

As it turns out, in Debug mode, `new` both "reserves" and "gives" memory to the program. Meanwhile, in Release mode, it only "reserves" it, as the memory is "given" by the loop. I expected only the behavior present in Release mode - I thought that the memory is "given" to the program only when a page fault occurs.

Why does `new` behave in this way? Does this have any significant implications?

---

<sup>1</sup> By the way, for some reason changing `auto* pages` to `auto* const pages` causes an Internal Compiler Error.

<sup>2</sup> I am a bit confused regarding the correct terminology, so I used "given" and "reserved" instead.

Comment: FYI: 1/ worth a bug report & 2/ "commited" versus "allocated" [What's the difference between reserved and committed memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2440434/5470596)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand what happened you need to know two things:

1. The debug  builds do a lot of cool stuff for you to help you find bugs. One is  writing a known value into the program's memory so you'll more easily recognize that you've messed around with uninitialized storage.
2. Modern memory management systems in CPUs are complicated, but one thing they all tend to do is *as little as possible* until they have to. When a program requests storage the underlying system checks that there is enough virtual addressing space and then almost always allows the request without filling it. No physical memory is found and assigned to the virtual memory. When the memory is accessed, then physical memory will be found and assigned or the program fails because memory was not available.

The combination of points 1 and 2 mean the debug version of `new` acquires the memory and immediately accesses it by writing in the uninitialized memory detection pattern and forcing the system to find and hand over real memory in the green region. As an added bonus if the computer does run out of physical storage, the program will likely crash here and not some seemingly random point in the future when the request cannot be satisfied.

The release version of `new` does not do point 1, so physical memory acquisition is deferred as per point 2. `new` exits the green region quickly without any physical memory. If some or all of the requested memory is never used, the computer profits by never having to do the work fulfilling the request. The program does use the requested storage in the `for` loop, so the system is forced to find and supply physical memory in the blue region.

Comment: Thanks, I never really noticed that before, but now I checked and verified that indeed in Debug mode the memory always gets initialised to `ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ...`.

Comment: @janekb04 [here's a decent list of popular debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values). If you see one of these, or something really close to one, in an error message, variable, or data stream, odds are the program's trying to tell you something important. Whenever you see a really weird number, convert it to hex and see if it's on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Otherwise, I wouldn't have suspected that `Í`(`CD` in hex) comes from [(23)](https://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) Clean Debug memory.

Answer (score 1):

Debug `new` fills memory with recognizable pattern.